# Get QueryPlan for storedprocedure which did not complete execution for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-performance, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have a sql job with multiple steps and one of them is having 5 stored procedures to be executed. For some reason the job was stuck on this step executing 4th stored procedure. Hence we had to kill it and restart the job with next steps.
Since I stopped the job without 4th SP completing, it would have rolledback. But I would like to know is there a way I can get the query plan for this stored procedure (which was running some INSERT command) ?
I tried to query the plan cache with filter on last_execution_time and the databaseID from dm_exec_query_stats. But this did not retrieve the query I wanted. How can I get the query plan for that query ?
We are using SQL 2016 but Query Store is not enabled for the database at the moment.

Comment: You can use SSMS to get the **estimated** query plan, however, like the name suggests it's estimated. The only "proper" way to actual query plan is to run it and have the actual query plan returned.

Comment: If it's not in the query plan cache, then you're out of luck. Run it again, either live or on a test setup, and this time under a profiler/extended event trace that will capture the execution plan. Note that whether a query executes successfully or not, you are not guaranteed to have a plan for it in the cache -- turnover on that cache can be substantial on a busy server.